# ROS2 node in C++ project

Tags: c++, ros2

I have created a ROS2 client node in C++ to run inference.
I need to run the first half of my code that needs the inference, to get the input for the service node, and then i need to run the other half of the source code with the output of the client node.
I cant seem to find any information about how to do this, and when I tried using the client node in my pipeline none of my code seemed to run.